# How do I find duplicate rows from XPATH result using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xslt, xpath, ghost-inspector

I'm using an XPATH to pull back a list of names:

```
//div[@class="col-sm-2"]//a[@ng-click="$ctrl.editName(name.NAMEID)"]
```

The results are simply lastname, firstname for about 20 people:

Smith, Joe
White, Barry
Sham, Sam
White, Barry
Rocks, Tony

I'm using the following XPATH with document.evaluate to find these values:

```
return document.evaluate('//div[@class="col-sm-2"]//a[@ng-click="$ctrl.editName(patient.NAMEID)"])', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).stringValue
```

I'm looking for some Javascript examples to see if there are ANY duplicate rows of names in the evaluated XPATH.